# Solvability of the (outer) automorphism group of a central product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G = A * B$ be a central product of the finite groups $A$ and $B$. Suppose that $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(B)$ are solvable groups. Then is $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ a solvable group?

And what about the same question with outer automorphism groups instead?

Comment: Where does $G$ come into play?

Comment: Typo, fixed! 15chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general no. A counterexample with the direct product to both questions is with $A$ and $B$ both cyclic of order $5$. ${\rm Aut}(A \times B) = {\rm GL}(2,5)$ is not solvable.

A counterexample with a genuine central product is $A=D_8$, $B=Q_8$, where again the outer automorphism group has $A_5$ as a composition factor.

Comment: Your first example is a genuine central product :)

Comment: Well I meant a central product that is not a direct product, but I expect you know that!